# accel-ppp без радиуса и дефолтные шейпы

Tags: linux, pppoe, ppp

Здравствуйте!
Имеется debian 8, ppp, accel-ppp **без радиуса** авторизующий всех желающих:

```
any-login=1
noauth=1
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью accel-ppp нарезать всем дефолтные шейпы, к примеру, в 10Мбит?

Answer (score 1):

После запуска демона прописать

```
accel-cmd shaper change all xxxx/xxxx temp
```

где хххх/хххх - входящая/исходящая скорости.